# Bootstrap tooltip is not working after filtering with ajax in Rails 4

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, ransack

I got an index page that shows multiple objects of `foo` and integrated a filter function with the gem [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) and this ajax script:

```
$('#foo_search input').change(function(){
    $.get($('#foos_search').attr('action'), $('#foos_search').serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
});
```

This is working just fine at the moment. After that I added a tooltip on each `foo` shown on the index page with [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips). JS-code looks like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Index page looks something like this:

```
//index.html.erb
<div id="foos">
  <%= render 'foos' %>
</div>

//_foos.html.erb
<% @foos.each do |f| %>
  <div class="btn btn-default">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="<% f.details.each do |d| %><li><%= d.name %></li><% end %>">
      DETAILS
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see each `foo` got a bunch of `details` and all details are supposed to show up in the tooltip. That works very well until I use my filter. As soon as I filter the `foo`s with ransack the JS will stop working and no tooltips will show until I reload the page.

Any ideas on this?

EDIT:
I uploaded the current version on heroku so maybe you could just have a look there. Since it's in German I will tell you how to get to the problem:
You will see the `foo` objects in bright yellow jumbtrons and if you hover over "Geeignet für" for example you will see a tooltip pop up. But as soon as you use the filter function on the left the tooltip wont work anymore and will instead show some html.

https://sheltered-escarpment-6887.herokuapp.com/list

EDIT2:
This is reloading the partial after changing filter options:

```
//index.js.erb
$("#foos").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("foos")) %>");
```

EDIT3:
Thanks so cassioscabral I figured it out:

```
//index.js.erb
$("#houses").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("houses")) %>");
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call the method `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` again so it can render the tooltip again.

I can't figure it out why your filter is affecting that. Maybe it renders(and add new dom elements) the partial after the search and since that element would be added after your initial `.tooltip()` call, calling again would be the right way since it's basically saying 'add the tooltip to all the elements with this `data-toggle`, including the new ones'

Comment: Okay, totally makes sense. But which way would be good to reload the plugin every time. I added the .js.erb file which is reloading the partial after using the filter. I guess it would make sense to add it in there.

Comment: I would rather bind the call to `.tooltip()` with the filter submit button. When filter is clicked you can check for a still active Ajax call happening, wait for this call to end then call `.tooltip()`

Comment: As you can see in my code the ajax is happening on every change in the filter form. I am not using a submit button at all.

Comment: Yeah, didn't saw that. You could add a success callback on that $.get also. But the bind(for every successful change apply `.tooltip()`) would also work with the change event.